# AWS linux add increased volume into a existing partition

Tags: linux, aws

I am using AWS for my production server.Yesteday my mongodb stopped running and it says there is no enough space for journling. To add more space I have edited the volumn in AWS console and increased the volumn size to 16Gib.result of lsblk on linux command line is as below

```
  lsblk
  NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  xvda    202:0    0  16G  0 disk
    └─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

Print command in parted shows the below result

```
 print
 Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
 Disk /dev/xvda: 17.2GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                 Flags
128     1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               BIOS Boot Partition  bios_grub
1      2097kB  8590MB  8588MB  ext4         Linux
2      8590MB  17.2GB  8590MB               Linux
```

and df-h shows the below result

```
 df -h
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.3G  3.5G  56% /
 devtmpfs        488M   56K  488M   1% /dev
 tmpfs           498M     0  498M   0% /dev/shm
```

I need to add the extra added space that is 8 GB to /dev/xvda1 without losing any thing on server. I am fairly new to linux servers. Any help or suggections are appreciated

EDIT1 - after google I also tried doing resize2fs but it shows following output

```
resize2fs /dev/xvda1
 resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
 The filesystem is already 2096635 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should make a complete backup before attempting anything like this.

You need to delete that 2nd partition from the partition table (e.g. with `gdisk` or `parted`), then extend the first partition to the end of the newly available space, and finally grow the filesystem so that it knows it has more storage available - this last step is different for every filesystem type.  e.g. if the fs is xfs, you'd use `xfs_growfs`.  For ext2/3/4, you'd use `resize2fs`.  There are several questions with good answers on this site about [growing a filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=grow+filesystem) - i very strongly recommend researching this subject extensively before attempting it.  It's not difficult but even small mistakes can cause catastrophic data loss.

Another alternative is to just create a new VM with a 16G or larger disk (or a smallish 1-4GB /dev/xvda boot/OS disk and a second larger /dev/xvdb disk for your database - which will make things simpler if you ever need to increase the storage space again).  Get the second VM working exactly the same as the original, and then copy the data over from the original VM to the new one.

`rsync` is probably best for copying - you can rsync the data while the original VM is still running and servicing requests to get the bulk of the data across, then shutdown the db service on it and rsync again to transfer any data that was added/changed/deleted since the first rsync started.  Then shutdown the original, and restart the new VM so that it has the same IP address etc as the original.  This will minimise downtime.